# get widget from QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlistwidget

I have a custom QWidget class called `VideoWidget` which I used to populate my QListWidget `ui->myList`. Doubleclicking on any item of the list should give me its `VideoWidget`.

```
connect(ui->myList,SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(playClip(QModelIndex)));

void MainWindow::playClip(QModelIndex index){
    QListWidgetItem* item = ui->myList->itemAt(0,index.row());
    VideoWidget widget = <dynamic_cast>(VideoWidget*)( ui->myList->itemWidget(item) );
    cout << "custom widget data" << widget.getMyData() << endl;
}
```

It won't let me compile the line `VideoWidget widget = <dynamic_cast>(VideoWidget*)( ui->myList->itemWidget(item) );`. I'm not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Syntax of `dynamic_cast` is

   ```
   VideoWidget *widget = dynamic_cast<VideoWidget*>(ui->myList->itemWidget(item));
   ```
2. You should probably use [`qobject_cast`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) instead, since that is a *QObject*:

   ```
   VideoWidget *widget = qobject_cast<VideoWidget*>(ui->myList->itemWidget(item));
   ```
3. Add code, at least `Q_ASSERT(widget);`, after the cast to verify that cast was successful (returns `nullptr` for failed cast).

Comment: it has to be `VideoWidget* widget =`, correct?. I'm getting the error **"static assertion failed: qobject_cast requires the type to have a Q_OBJECT macro"** when I do it with `qobject_cast`
                                               ^

Comment: what about the error? I do have the Q_OBJECT macro in my MainWindow header

Comment: @testus Yes, any QObject subclass must have the Q_OBJECT macro. Use Qt Creator new class wizard to create new classes so you don't forget. In this case, you could create a dummy class just to see what it puts there, in .h file and in constructor.

Comment: Also, remember to list the .h file in the .pro file HEADERS, I think otherwise it will not be processed by *moc* (which is what creates the Qt meta object information needed by signals and slots and reflection).

Comment: I'm using the QT created MainWindow class. Header and consturctor don't have any big changes. I just remembered that I did comment out Q_OBJECT in my VideoWidget because it didn't allow me to compile my custom widget before when the macro is there (error was "undefined reference to `vtable for VideoWidget'"). Is that the problem?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Had to run qmake again. Now I can use qobject_cast without any problems. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your line does not make sense. `<dynamic_cast>` is not valid C++. It is an invalid name, and can't be a template parameter, since no template expecting function/class is before it.

It would have been `dynamic_cast<VideoWidget*> (ui->myList->itemWidget(item) )` in C++

However, Qt defines it own casting function, so you should  use `qobject_cast<VideoWidget*>(ui->myList->itemWidget(item) )`